# JSON Value into SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a requirement to insert values into table. I have to create stored procedure. This SP is part of API, when a user "Save" data on UI, this API will call and execute this SP. Below if JSON format, I get from UI.

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.test 
 (
      Quarter,
      Entity,
      Schooldetails, 
      Teachername,
      Teachid,
      Observation
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.test1 
(
     username,
     Age,
     Id,
     CtrName,
     Rank,
     Levelid,
     business
) - two records will be inserted


"Easy" : {
   "Quarter": "2nd Q"
   "Entity": "ABC"
   "Schooldetails": [{
 "Username": "Dinesh,K",
 "Age": "45",
 "Id": "1"
     }, {
   "Username": "Dinesh,K",
    "Age": "45",
    "Id": "1"
   }
 ],
 "Teachername": "Suni",
 "Teachid" : "123",
 "Additionalinfo":[{
    "CtrName": "test1",
    "Rank": "1",
    "Levelid": "lvl1",
    "business": "forest"
 },{
    "CtrName": "test2",
    "Rank": "2",
    "Levelid": "lvl2",
    "business": "air"
 }
 ],
 "Observation": "1"
 }
```

I tried this but didn't work. It is throwing an error...when I try using postman.
Error message on postman:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '{' is found at position 9.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.TEST @easy VARCHAR(max) 
as
Begin
  Set @json = '{ "Easy": {' + @easy + '} }'

begin try
 begin trans

insert into dbo.test 
 (
      Quarter,
      Entity,
      Schooldetails, 
      Teachername,
      Teachid,
      Observation
)
(
select JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Quarter')  Quarter,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Entity')  Entity,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Schooldetails')  Schooldetails,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Teachername')  Teachername,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Teachid')  Teachid,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Observation')  Observation from OPENJSON(@json, '$.easy') as easy

insert into dbo.test1
 (
     username,
     Age,
     Id,
     CtrName,
     Rank,
     Levelid,
     business
)
(
select JSON_Value (a.value, '$.username')  username,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Age')  Age,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Id')  Id,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.CtrName)  CtrName,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Rank')  Rank,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Levelid')  Levelid,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.business')  business
 from OPENJSON(@json, '$.easy') as easy1 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(easy1.value, '$.Schooldetails') as b
)

insert into dbo.test1
 (
     username,
     Age,
     Id,
     CtrName,
     Rank,
     Levelid,
     business
)
(
select 
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.CtrName)  CtrName,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Rank')  Rank,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.Levelid')  Levelid,
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.business')  business
 from OPENJSON(@json, '$.easy') as easy1 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(easy1.value, '$.Additionalinfo') as b
)
```

Comment: do you want to read data from JSON string and insert into the above 2 mentioned tables in sql server ?

Comment: Yes i want to above json into two tables.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. It needs a single starting brace, commas at end of lines 2 and 3, and no extra ending braces. There is no `Schooldetails` property so it's unclear what you were trying to do there. And if you `CROSS APPLY` twice you will get duplicated rows

Answer (score 0):

> "OPENJSON is a table-valued function that helps to parse JSON in SQL
> Server and it returns the data values and types of the JSON text in a
> table format. Now, we will look at the syntax of this function."

```
OPENJSON( jsonExpression  [, jsonPath ] )
[ WITH (column_mapping_definition1
        [,column_mapping_definition2] 
        [,… column_mapping_definitionN])
]
```

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-parse-json-in-sql-server/

***EDIT AFTER QUESTION EDITED AFTER SUGGESTED ANSWER***

You are missing a single quote in the following line of 2nd and 3rd `select` clause:

```
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.CtrName)  CtrName,
```

Please change to the following:

```
JSON_Value (a.value, '$.CtrName')  CtrName,
```

Comment: Suggesting how to solve the problem is not an answer - a helpful comment maybe. Answers need to fully answer the question.

Comment: I tried with the code.,..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/437941/json-value-into-sql-server.html?childToView=438229#answer-438229 but didn't work

Comment: @DineshKal What version of SqlServer are you on and what exactly didn't work? What error did you get?

Comment: @DineshKal you are missing single quote on this line: JSON_Value (a.value, '$.CtrName)  CtrName,